# How to properly pattern match JsonConversions

Tags: f#, f#-data

Hi I have the following code which works as I expect but the compiler warns me about incomplete pattern matching when I pattern match in the `Option.defaultWith` function. Is there a smarter way to achieve the same effect but without warnings?

I have been thinking about throwing an exception for the rest of the cases but that's pretty ugly.

```
namespace JsonParser

open System
open System.Globalization
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.Runtime

type public Key = string

type public Value =
    | Int of int
    | Double of double
    | Decimal of decimal
    | String of string
    | DateTime of DateTime
    | Boolean of Boolean
    | Array of Value []
    | Guid of Guid
    | Null
    | Object of Record []

and public Record =
    { Key: Key
      Value: Value }

module public Json =

    let private culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    let private emptyArray = Array.empty<String>

    let rec private map (value: JsonValue) =
        JsonConversions.AsInteger culture value
        |> Option.map Value.Int
        |> Option.orElseWith (fun () -> JsonConversions.AsDecimal culture value |> Option.map Value.Decimal)
        |> Option.orElseWith (fun () -> JsonConversions.AsFloat emptyArray true culture value |> Option.map Decimal |> Option.map Value.Decimal)
        |> Option.orElseWith (fun () -> JsonConversions.AsGuid value |> Option.map Value.Guid)
        |> Option.orElseWith (fun () -> JsonConversions.AsDateTime culture value |> Option.map Value.DateTime)
        |> Option.orElseWith (fun () -> JsonConversions.AsBoolean value |> Option.map Value.Boolean)
        |> Option.defaultWith (fun () ->
            match value with
            | JsonValue.String x -> Value.String x
            | JsonValue.Null -> Value.Null
            | JsonValue.Array x ->
                x
                |> Array.map map
                |> Value.Array
            | JsonValue.Record x ->
                x
                |> Array.map (fun (x, y) ->
                    { Key = x
                      Value = map y })
                |> Value.Object)
```

Comment: Why don't you just match on JsonValue.Null (etc) and in the String case you can try to parse as DateTime, Guid, etc. Your code would be (IMO) a lot more readable.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. I have a similar approach implemented today. But what's the best practice to get the most out of the `JsonValue`?

Comment: I think the whole point of the JsonValue discriminated union is so you can match a parsed value against it to determine what it really is. Which you are already doing, but after you run through all those Option.orElseWith statements. Just match it on right away. Does that help?

Comment: But for the cases where I want to parse for example `Guid` and `DateTime` . It would require me to pass the `JsonValue.String` into an additional parse function.

In my ideal scenario, I would like to have a simple pattern matching where those cases are included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer really depends on how you want to handle various corner cases in your JSON data.

The operations in `JsonConversions` are implemented in a way where they attempt to convert the value to the target type whenever this can reasonably be done. This means that using those, a value `true`, `1` and `"yes"` will all be converted to boolan `true`. Is this what you want? If so, then I would probably just add a case to the pattern match that throws an exception, saying that the situation should not happen:

```
match value with
| JsonValue.String x -> Value.String x
| JsonValue.Null -> Value.Null
| JsonValue.Array x -> (...)
| JsonValue.Record x -> (...)
| JsonValue.Float _ | JsonValue.Number _ | JsonValue.Boolean _ -> 
    failwith "should never happen: Numbers and booleans handled earlier!"
```

If you want to turn JSON value `"yes"` to  `Value.String("yes")` rather than to `Value.Boolean(true)`, then it is a lot easier if you directly pattern match on `JsonValue`:

```
let rec private map (value: JsonValue) =
    match value with
    | JsonValue.Float f -> Value.Double f
    | JsonValue.Number n -> Value.Decimal n 
    | JsonValue.Boolean b -> Value.Boolean b
    | JsonValue.String x -> Value.String x
    | JsonValue.Null -> Value.Null
    | JsonValue.Array x ->
        x |> Array.map map |> Value.Array
    | JsonValue.Record x ->
        x |> Array.map (fun (x, y) -> { Key = x; Value = map y }) |> Value.Object
```

You can find the details about how `JsonConversions` work by looking at the relevant file in the source code: [JsonConversions](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/27def771dec8c0069f4fc0f17a11554d846666a9/src/Json/JsonConversions.fs) and [TextConversions](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/27def771dec8c0069f4fc0f17a11554d846666a9/src/CommonRuntime/TextConversions.fs).

Comment: Ah, I see, In my initial implementation I started with a simple pattern matching over `JsonValue` but I wanted to be able to map to  `Guid` and `DateTime`.


Which made me do `Guid.TryParse` etc when I got strings, but I was thinking `JsonConversions` would be the solution rather than using my functions to glue it together and it ended up with my sample code here.

Comment: Thanks for your input!